# Hide division - IE (css, not js)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to hide division, but not using JS.

```
<div id="myDiv" hidden>
</div>
```

This works well in Chrome, FF, but not on IE, how do I fix it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gjHu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the style

```
 display:none;
```

:-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `visibility:hidden` if you want to hide the element, but it will still take up the same space as before. Just use `display:none` to hide it the same way, but it will not take up space anymore.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply change it to

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
</div>
```